# Разобрать список на C#

Tags: c#

В бд имеется таблица, которая хранит дерево данных, и имеет примерно следующий вид: id, tree, name

Т.е. id записи, tree указывает на принадлежность к тому или иному узлу, и собственно name - т.е. имя узла

Так вот, tree имеет записи вида:

```
 1. 
  1.1.
  1.1.1
  1.1.2
1.2.
  1.2
  1.2.1
```

Хотелось бы все это распарсить и отобразить в TreeView, но пока не знаю каким образом даже подойти к этой задаче( Подозреваю что есть какое-то простое решение, и нет необходимости изобретать велосипед

Comment: Что вы пробовали, какой код написали, что у вас не получилось?

Comment: Честно говоря это пока только знакомство с c#. До этого был опыт с php. Пока только учусь, поэтому прошу сильно не пинать.

Comment: Для начала, ответ зависит от вашего выбранного UI-фреймворка. В самом C# вообще нету TreeView.

Comment: @VladD, по умолчанию же winforms подразумевается, а wpf надо называть явно?

Comment: @Qwertiy: Кому как. Я, например, считаю WinForms отжившим своё анахронизмом, у которого даже layout manager'а нету. А кто-то, наоборот, считает WPF жутким тормознутым монстром с нечитаемым XML в синтаксисе и невозможностью нормальной отладки. А кто-то вообще считает, что эпоха толстых клиентов прошла, и надо выдавать данные в Web, поэтому единственный нормальный фреймворк — ASP.NET. А ещё кто-нибудь считает всё, кроме GTK#, отстоем, ибо не кроссплатформенно. В общем, tastes differ.

Comment: @VladD, я про распространённость, а не про вкусы. Из коробки в VS есть только winforms и wpf, причём первое распространённее. Так?

Comment: @Qwertiy: У меня в 2012-ой студии ещё ASP.NET и Silverlight. А насчёт распространённости, у меня нет ни одного личного знакомого, пишущего на WinForms. (И есть много, пишущих на WPF.) Поэтому лично я WinForms вообще не рассматриваю как UI framework.

Comment: @VladD, Silverlight-то точно умер. Он даже не взлетел. Что в нём есть, не знаю. ASP.NET - тоже старьё, сейчас ASP.NET MVC, в котором TreeView нет. Да и вообще, неявно спрашивать про web было бы ооочень странно.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Угу, там MVC и WebForms (что бы это ни было). А на SL я видел даже пару приложений. Так что всё же взлетел, но не высоко. В любом случае, я за то, чтобы авторы вопросов хоть узнали о существовании нормальных UI-фреймворков.

Comment: @VladD, WebForms - это как winforms, только для web. Этог совсем ужасно. Кажется, в 2015й студии его наконец-то выпилили :) А у сильверлайта с кроссбраузерностью проблемы. В смысле, что он работает в IE, а в остальных его либо нет, либо он глючит.

Comment: @Alexey Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<Header> list = new List<Header>()
        {
            new Header() 
                { 
                    Name = "1",
                    List = new List<Header>()
                    {
                        new Header() 
                        { 
                            Name = "1.1",
                            List = new List<Header>()
                            {
                                new Header() { Name = "1.1.1"},
                                new Header() { Name = "1.1.2"},
                                new Header() { Name = "1.1.3"},
                            }
                        },
                        new Header() { Name = "1.2"},
                        new Header() { Name = "1.3"},
                    }
                },
            new Header() 
            { 
                Name = "2",
                List = new List<Header>()
                    {
                        new Header() 
                        { 
                            Name = "2.1",
                            List = new List<Header>()
                            {
                                new Header() { Name = "2.1.1"},
                                new Header() { Name = "2.1.2"},
                                new Header() { Name = "2.1.3"},
                            }
                        },
                        new Header() { Name = "2.2"},
                        new Header() { Name = "2.3"},
                    }}
        };

        treeView1.Nodes.Add("Headers");

        BuildTreeView(list, treeView1.Nodes[0]);
    }

    private void BuildTreeView(List<Header> list, TreeNode parentNode)
    {
        if (list.Count != 0)
        {
            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                TreeNode tn = new TreeNode(item.Name);

                parentNode.Nodes.Add(tn);
                if (item.List != null)
                {
                    BuildTreeView(item.List, tn);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

sealed class Header
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Header> List { get; set; }
}
}
```

Собственно, если у Вас есть уже структура данных, то можете просто использовать метод для построения дерева.

Мой пример выводит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3):

Складываешь всё в `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` с `id` в качестве ключа и всей записью в качестве значения. Через `foreach` проходишь по нему и добавляешь детей родительскому элементу, а все записи с пустым родителем складываешь в список. В итоге получится лес.